# What do I need to do to get libegl.lib on windows7?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, egl

What do I need to do to get libEGL.lib on windows7?

Google is telling me I already should have OpenGL by default, but I need to link against a 32 bit version of libegl.lib to compile QtWebKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab a copy of [ANGLE](http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/) (for hardware rendering via D3D9/D3D11) or [Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/) (for software rendering).

Both provide EGL and OpenGL ES 2.0 implementations.

Comment: @patrickinmpls: As mentioned ANGLE is a translation layer that implements OpenGL ES 2.0 on top of D3D9/D3D11, but AMD actually provides a direct hardware interface to EGL on Microsoft Windows and Linux [here](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/amd-opengl-es-sdk/). NVIDIA got really lazy, sadly and you have to create a traditional WGL render context and load an OpenGL ES interop. extension, no implementation of the EGL API from NV; this is actually kind of surprising, usually it would be the other way around when it comes to anything OpenGL.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use PowerVR SDK: http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp

there is implementation for GLES2.0 and GLES 3.0 as well